# Why state is null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

After authorization and redirect to `/userProfile` page I get error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null.

I have `<Page />` component.

Code of that:

```
const Page = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
                <h1>{`${userData.name} ${userData.surname}`}</h1>
                <button onClick={() => logout()} style={{display: "block"}}
                        className="btn btn-large ">
                    Выйти</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

It uses value from state named userData through useState hook

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({name: "", surname: "", posts: [], email: "", password: ""});
```

I fetch data in useEffect hook

```
const request = useCallback(async (url, method = 'POST', body = null, headers = {}) => {
    setLoading(true)
    try {
        if (body) {
            body = JSON.stringify(body)
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        }
        const response = await fetch(url, {method, body, headers});
        const data = await response.json();
        setLoading(false);
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        setLoading(false)
        throw e
    }
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
    const response = request("/api/user/getDataByUserId", "POST", {userId: userId});
    response.then(r => {
        setUserData(r.data);
    });
}, [request, userId]);
```

userId I get from AuthContext
I have tried to solve this problem for two days, please HELP ME

Comment: What is the component in which you have your request method

Comment: It seems `<Page />` component does not have access to `userData`. Where do you use that component? Maybe you can try to pass `userData` through `props`.

Comment: I have completely found the solving. I needed to change h1 tag to {userData && <h1>{`${userData.name} ${userData.surname}`}</h1>} checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check  " setUserData(r.data) " inside useEffect, try doing console.log on r and r.data. The problem may be that r.data setting userData as null. If its coming null you can set default or invalid as per requirement.

Checking as "userData && {${userData.name} ${userData.surname}" will be a good practice and better way of doing it will be to make a function getFullNameMarkup and do the checks inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed h1 tag to `{userData && <h1>`{`${userData.name} ${userData.surname`}`}</h1>}` and it is working